# Perl: Print a String Containing an Excel Hyperlink

Tags: excel, perl

I need to print something along the lines of this into an excel file:

```
=HYPERLINK("file:///Users/me/folders/filename", "Display_Name")
```

Every time I do so, the cell I'm trying to print into takes the value

```
=HYPERLINK(file:///Users/me/folders/filename"
```

Where it is missing a double quote before "file", and does not contain the whole string! Rather, the cell adjacent takes the value

```
 Display_Name")"
```

Where there is an extra double quote, and a missing comma.

This is what I have so far to assign the value of the variable that gets outputted to that cell:

```
$string = "=HYPERLINK(\"file:///Users/me/folders/" . "$filename \" \, Display_Name\")";
```

(The filename is another variable since I print this string in various cells leading to different files in the same folder)

**EDIT:**
This is the way I am writing to the .csv files (with the $string suggestion from Borodin):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $sname = "test";
my $outfile = "$sname.csv";
open my $OUTFILE, ">", $outfile or 
  die "ERROR: Unable to open output file $outfile\n";
my @output;
my $file_name    = 'file_name.txt';
my $display_name = 'Display Name';

my $string = sprintf '=HYPERLINK("%s", "%s")',
        "file:///Users/me/folders/$file_name",
        $display_name;
$output[1]=$string;
print $OUTFILE @output, "\n";
```

This still produces one cell that reads

```
=HYPERLINK("file:///Users/me/folders/file_name.txt"
```

And one that reads

```
 "Display Name")
```

Comment: What module are you using to create the Excel file? Please [edit] and add some example code to reproduce this.

Comment: Everything depends on whjat you are doing with `$string`, and you don't show that part of your code. As [simbabque suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805496/perl-print-a-string-containing-an-excel-hyperlink#comment64979830_38805496) there is no way to know what may be wrong with your program until you show it. Please write an equivalent program that creates a spreadsheet with just a *single cell* containing this function that misbehaves in the same way. That would be a part of the debugging process anyway, and we will be able to help you when we can debug the code for ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to escape multiple double-quote characters within a quoted string. Perl offers many much neater ways to construct the string that you want

Also, the `print` operator is a very useful thing, and usually better than shutting your eyes before you run your code

The output from your code doesn't look right at all. Did you look at it?

```perl
use v5.10;

my $filename = 'file_name.txt';

my $string = "=HYPERLINK(\"file:///Users/me/folders/" . "$filename \" \, Display_Name\")";

say $string;
```

#### output

```
=HYPERLINK("file:///Users/me/folders/file_name.txt " , Display_Name")
```

The output has a space before the closing double quote on the URL, and no opening quote on the display name

How about this?

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $file_name    = 'file_name.txt';
my $display_name = 'Display Name';

my $string = sprintf '=HYPERLINK("%s", "%s")',
        "file:///Users/me/folders/$file_name",
        $display_name;

print $string, "\n";
```

#### output

```
=HYPERLINK("file:///Users/me/folders/file_name.txt", "Display Name")
```